# Telling JS when AS's ExternalInterface is ready

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex

SOLVED: I should have added more detail. Even though the External Interface was set up the NetConnection/NetStream objects were not connected to the server. As a result, I couldn't make any calls thru. A very important detail I left out, apologies.

I know that it's proper to have Flash call back to JavaScript when External Interface is ready so I make the call. The JS method gets called correctly but I am unable to then trigger a successful call back to the Flash file. I have to manually set a 1-second timeout to get it to work and I don't understand why. If the External Interface is ready then I should be able to call back to Flash right away, right?

By the way, I'm using `SWFObject.embedSWF()` to place the Flash file on the page. I've given the file an id and name attributes.

Here's my flash code:

```
    private function init():void // onCreationComplete handler
    {
        this.setupExternalInterface();
    }

    private function setupExternalInterface():void
    {
        if (ExternalInterface.available)
        {
            ExternalInterface.call("swfIsReady");
            ExternalInterface.addCallback("call", makeACall);
        }
    }
```

And here's the JSP page:

```
    function swfIsReady(){
        setTimeout(flexCall,1000);
    }

   function flexCall(){
       var theApp = getFlexApp(attributes.name);
       theApp.call();   
   }

   function getFlexApp(appName)
   {
       if (navigator.appName.indexOf ("Microsoft") !=-1)
       {
           return window[appName];
       }
       else
       {
           return document[appName];
       }
   }
```

This is the only way it works. I thought I could just remove the timeout and call flexCall() directly.

Comment: What happens if you flip-flop the two lines where you do `ExternalInterface.call()` and `ExternalInterface.addCallback()`. Add the callback first, then tell Javascript that external interface is ready... it may not help, just thinking out loud...

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work. But thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have two little problems in your code :

- The first problem is using the [`call()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) method which is used in JavaScript to [invoke a function](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_function_invocation.asp).

Try this (I'm not sure that's working but to more see the problem) :

```
swf_obj.call.call();
```

but the solution is simply to use another name of your callback function :

```
swf_obj.make_call();
```

- The second one, is calling `ExternalInterface.addCallback()` after `ExternalInterface.call()` which you can just inverse their order to get it working.

So your code can be like this for example :

**ActionScript :**

```
private function init(event:FlexEvent):void
{
    setupExternalInterface();
}
private function setupExternalInterface():void
{
    if (ExternalInterface.available)
    {   
        ExternalInterface.addCallback("make_call", makeACall);              
        ExternalInterface.call("swfIsReady");                                       
    }
}
```

**JavaScript :**

```
function swfIsReady()
{
    var swf_obj= swfobject.getObjectById(attributes.name);
    if (swf_obj) {
        swf_obj.make_call();
    }
}
```

Hope that can help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. First off, the .call() was just me using pseudo-code. The actual method wasn't named that and yes, I am now aware that .call() creates a new object in JS. The real problem was that I was calling back to the JSP page when the external interface was set up and was not properly waiting for the connection to the server to be established. This is why it was failing. I needed to wait for the NetStream to be connected before I could start making calls. Apologies, I should have been much more clear.

Comment: @fumeng No problem. But as you know, we answer the question according to what we see and understand nothing else ;)